# i2c values for UPS-Lite v1.2 report 0 in python, but correctly in cli

Tags: raspbian, python, i2c, pi-zero, ups

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero WH and I'm trying to read the voltage and capacity values in Python from my UPS-Lite v1.2 battery, but they're reporting zeros despite the CLI showing differently.

I've read through these resources:

- https://github.com/linshuqin329/UPS-Lite/blob/master/Instructions%20for%20UPS-Lite%20V1.2.pdf
- https://hackaday.io/project/173847-ups-lite

```bsh
# Environment

$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.4.79+ #1373 Mon Nov 23 13:18:15 GMT 2020 armv6l GNU/Linux
$ ls -l $(which python)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Dec 14 19:08 /usr/bin/python -> python3
$ python --version
Python 3.7.3

# I2C Troubleshooting

$ sudo i2cdetect -l
i2c-1   i2c         bcm2835 (i2c@7e804000)              I2C adapter
$ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- 36 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --     
$ sudo i2cget -y 1 0x36 2     # 2 is voltage address
0xd2
$ sudo i2cget -y 1 0x36 4     # 4 is capacity address
0x66
```

My Python code looks like this.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import smbus
import struct
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

ADDRESS = 0x36

def readVoltage(bus):
    try:
        read = bus.read_word_data(ADDRESS, 2)
        logging.info("voltage read: " + str(read))
        swapped = struct.unpack("<H", struct.pack(">H", read))[0]
        logging.info("voltage swapped: " + str(swapped))
        voltage = swapped * 1.25 / 1000 / 16
        logging.info("voltage return: " + str(voltage))
        return voltage
    except:
        return 0.0

def readCapacity(bus):
    try:
        read = bus.read_word_data(ADDRESS, 4)
        logging.info("capacity read: " + str(read))
        swapped = struct.unpack("<H", struct.pack(">H", read))[0]
        logging.info("capacity swapped: " + str(swapped))
        capacity = swapped / 256
        logging.info("capacity return: " + str(capacity))
        return capacity
    except:
        return 0.0

def QuickStart(bus):
    address = 0x36
    bus.write_word_data(address, 0x06, 0x4000)

def PowerOnReset(bus):
    address = 0x36
    bus.write_word_data(address, 0xfe, 0x0054)

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
PowerOnReset(bus)
QuickStart(bus)

print("Voltage: %5.2fV" % readVoltage(bus))
print("Capacity: %5i%%" % readCapacity(bus))
```

```bsh
$ sudo ./test.py
INFO:root:voltage read: 0
INFO:root:voltage swapped: 0
INFO:root:voltage return: 0.0
Voltage:  0.00V
INFO:root:capacity read: 0
INFO:root:capacity swapped: 0
INFO:root:capacity return: 0.0
Capacity:     0%
```

I've tried python3-smbus from apt-get and [SMBus2](https://pypi.org/project/smbus2/) from pip3.  Both report zero values.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Should ADDRESS be defined as a global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out!  This is confusing and I do not know why this caused a problem, but the values report properly in python if I don't set `PowerOnReset`.  Comment out that function call and they report properly:

```bsh
$ sudo ./test.py
INFO:root:voltage read: 16594
INFO:root:voltage swapped: 53824
INFO:root:voltage return: 4.205
Voltage:  4.21V
INFO:root:capacity read: 26726
INFO:root:capacity swapped: 26216
INFO:root:capacity return: 102.40625
Capacity:   102%
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as an unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

i2cget is reading one byte.

read_word_data is reading two bytes.

The read_word_data is probably illegal for the device and fails.

Try read_byte_data to get one byte as in the i2cget.

Comment: Interesting observation!  Though I did take the code right from the user manual.  It works now that I stopped setting the `PowerOnReset` flag (writing `0x54` to `0xfe`)  I have no idea why though 